# Redirecting script, with PHP after form hashing

Tags: php

I've just started coding in PHP and I'm stuck with redirection. I've accepted the $_POST information from the submitted form and assigned them to variables. I receive 2 password variables : $password and $c_password. My aim is to check if both these passwords match, if they do I want to hash them. If not I want to send the user back ( redirect ) to the register.php page. Problem is if I block everything below the javascript redirection, it works. But if I don't block the script after the js redirection, the user gets registered on the DB and gets redirected to the login.php page. Here's what I've coded so far :

```
<?php

// Open database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

// check existence and accept form data
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['c_password'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$c_password = $_POST['c_password'];
}

// Hash the password if password and c_password match
if(strcmp($password, $c_password) == 0) {
$password = hash('sha512',$_POST['password']);
} 
else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.location = './register.php?pass_nomatch=1';
    </script>
<?php
}

// Create a random salt
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

// Create salted password (Careful not to over season)
$password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

// Add your insert to database script here. 
// Make sure you use prepared statements!
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {    
$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt); 
// Execute the prepared query.
$insert_stmt->execute();
// Close MYSQL database connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
// Redirect user to login page
header('Location: ./login.php');
}

?>
```

If any one has an answer to my question please reply as soon as possible :)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by redirection? you mean, redirect user to another page?

Comment: I not exactly sure what your question is, but I would suggest using headers to redirect (header("Location: url/");) like what you do at the end rather than javascript, like you do in the middle.

Comment: @Matt I did try the header('register.php?pass_nomatch=1'); but it doesn't work if there is any code after the header();

Comment: @user2372971 check my answer. you forgot to put `Location:` inside the `header()` as in: `header('Location: register.php?pass_nomatch=1'); die('something');`

Comment: @phpNoOb I've put the Location: inside the header() and I've also tried adding die(); but the script just continues and inserts the user to my DB even if $password and $c_password do no match.

Comment: @user2372971 do the password verification method I used in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect a page in PHP, you can use the built-in function [**`header()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php);

ex: `header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/page.php')`

Remember, it is important that you put, an Absolute path, as argument to the header. Here is why from [**Wikipedia: HTTP_location**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location).

> The internet standard requires an absolute URI to follow a Location
>   header, which means it must contain a scheme[4] (e.g., http:, https:,
>   telnet:, mailto:)[5] and conforms to scheme-specific syntax and
>   semantics. For example, the HTTP scheme-specific syntax and semantics
>   for HTTP URLs requires a "host" (web server address) and "absolute
>   path", with optional components of "port" and "query". In the case
>   that there is no absolute path present, it must be given as "/" when
>   used as a request URI for a resource.[6]

Now, matching the passwords should be as easy, as:

```
if($passwordA === $passwordB) {
    // === is called, identity comparison operator. 
   // http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

else{ 
    header('Location: http://site.com/register.php?pass_nomatch=1');
    die("If you are not redirected in 5 seconds, click <a href='#'>here<a/> ");
  }
```

Comment: I want to redirect the user to the register.php page if the password matching fails. Is that possible ?

Comment: php NoOb , thanks for the solution.. works like a charm :D .. what's the difference between if($password == $c_password) and if($password === $c_password) ?

Comment: @user2372971 `==` will check for value meaning, `1 == '1'` will be true, even though the first `1` is integer(number) and the second `1` is text(string), but when you are using `===` it needs to check if both are numbers or both are strings, so `1 === '1'` will be false, because their identity is not same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/page.php');
```

and then halt the script:

```
die();
```

This will guarantee that the script stops.

Comment: Correct. Calling `header` in PHP does nothing else but to put another HTTP response header to send on the “heap” – but it does not influence further script execution. If one wants to end a script after outputting a (redirect) header and have none of the following code executed any more, one has to do it explicitly using `die()` or `exit`.